# Django error : Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly

Tags: python, django

I defined this class in  `views.py`:

> ```
> class EditOrderStudents(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
>
>     #permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
>     authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication , )
>     serializer_class =newOrdersStudentSerializidGet
>
>     def get_queryset(self):
>
>         id = self.request.query_params.get('id')
>         queryset = newOrdersStudent.objects.filter(Groupid=(id))
>         return queryset
> ```

and I use  the  `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` generic to put , delete and get method

but I got this error and I dont know what is the problem?

```
AssertionError: Expected view EditOrderStudents to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your URL configuration,

```
path('edit/<int:pk>/', EditOrderStudents.as_view(), name='edit')
```

run your app and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/1/